# What were the clues to where the ship had been in Event Horizon?

Tags: spaceship, space, event-horizon

In this film the ship has come back from apparently another dimension, are there any clues of where it might have been or what was there? I know there is mention Hell a few times but i was never sure throughout the film whether this was meant to be taken literally?

Comment: I think you're not supposed to know where the ship was. It's much scarier if you don't, actually. According to H.P.Lovecraft: “The oldest and strongest emotion of mankind is fear, and the oldest and strongest kind of fear is fear of the unknown”. The less you know, the creepier it is.

Comment: Fair enough and true! It was a pretty scary film and I guess not knowing contributed to this

Comment: There's a popular fan theory that it went through The Bleed from the WH40K universe, but of course, that's not canon.

Comment: "The Warp"... "The Bleed" is from Wildstorm comics.

Answer (score 4):

Although the [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Event-Horizon.html) is pretty vague, there's enough contextual clues to make a reasonable assumption that the ship was actually in hell.

- The distress call literally translates as "***Save yourself. From
  Hell***"
- Justins states that he's been in "*The other place*", again a clear
  reference to Hell
- The script refers to Miller being shown "**VISIONS FROM HELL**"

Comment: Wow thats pretty grim!

Comment: Maybe it was intended (by the directors) to be hell. But it can't _be_ hell if wasn't discovered before the term was coined, can it? As such, it can be _like hell_ but it cannot be 'the hell', imho. Just my philosophical 2 cents.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla Eh, people read stories about China before landing their ships there, right?

Comment: Because _someone_ was there first and came back to tell. They sure as hell didn't read stories about America before they landed their ships there (because noone went there yet), which is why they called it India at the time.

Comment: I could tell prospective employees/co-workers "save yourself. from hell." and not actually mean that my workplace is literally hell.

Comment: I cant remember what Weir says but its something like "Hell is just a word you cant imagine what its actually like", and it seemed he was implying where they went was Hell as in THE Hell? Are there other perhaps religious connotations throughout the film?

Comment: " "The other place", again a clear reference to Hell" - doesn't seem so clear

Comment: Heaven is heaven,  hell is often referred to as the other place in literature.

Comment: "the other place" is often a reference to hell, when in discussions about heaven. But "heaven" is never mentioned once [in the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Event-Horizon.html) (by that term, at least). without context, "the other place" could mean his mother in law's house or south korea, or any *other place*.

Comment: I'll accept that but I'll still point at the fact that they're shown "visions from hell"

Comment: '"the other place" could mean his mother in law's house ...' lol :)

Comment: @RobertF - I'd argue that a lot of people would consider that one step **below** hell.